# How can i Parse this xml using NSXMLParser in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

```
<root>
    <table name="radios">
        <column name="nameradio">Radio1</column>
        <column name="logo">http://app.syndicationradio.fr/demo/logo1.png</column>
        <column name="stream">http://cloud2.syndicationradio.fr:8020</column>
        <column name="twitter">http://www.twitter.com/#syndicationradio</column>
        <column name="facebook">http://www.facebook.com/syndicationradio</column>
        <column name="titre">http://app.syndicationradio.fr/demo/title.xml</column>
    </table>
    <table name="radios">
        <column name="nameradio">Radio2</column>
        <column name="logo">http://app.syndicationradio.fr/demo/logo1.png</column>
        <column name="stream">http://cloud2.syndicationradio.fr:8020</column>
        <column name="twitter">http://www.twitter.com/#syndicationradio</column>
        <column name="facebook">http://www.facebook.com/syndicationradio</column>
        <column name="titre">http://app.syndicationradio.fr/demo/title.xml</column>
    </table>
</root>
```

Now please is there anybody help to find out that, how can i get those url from the xml data using `NSXMLParser` or any other xml parser suppose `TBXML` in IOS?

Edit: you can also give me example of `libxml` parser for this xml.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"yourURL"];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    BOOL result = [parser parse];
    // Do whatever with the result
}
               
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"Did start element");
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"]) {
        NSLog(@"found rootElement");
        return;
    }
}
        
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"Did end element");
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"]) {
        NSLog(@"rootelement end");
    }           
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *tagName = @"column";
    if ([tagName isEqualToString:@"column"]) {
        NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a string, not a url: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somewebsite.com/RunPHPtoOutputXML.php?id=%d", ii]; //ii is an integer  I then run the following and am getting the XML: NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];

Comment: @user3741598 Exactly what you wanna ask ?

Comment: I got cut off - too many characters - will open a new question. Although I just came up with a potential quick, dirty possible answer at work that I will try when I get home. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

Ok you asked for a `libxml` example. I used it in a project but with `TBXML` instead of `NSXMLParser` because this one caused important problems of encoding and data retrieving.

First you have to download `TBXML.m` and `TBXML.h` files from the web and import them into your project. Then you also have to link `libxml2.dylib` to your project in **Link Binary with Libraries**.

Once this done, you will have to do this to retrieve your data (based on your XML source) :

```
NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL];
TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML newTBXMLWithXMLData:data error:nil];
[self getData:tbxml.rootXMLElement];

- (void) getData : (TBXMLElement *) element
{
    do {
        if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"table"])
        {
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"column"])
            { 
                if([[TBXML attributeName:element] isEqualToString:@"nameradio"])
                {
                    // You decide what to do here
                }
            }
        }
        if (element->firstChild) [self getData:element->firstChild];
    } while(element = element->nextSibling);
}
```

You probably will have to change this code but here you have all the basic things you need.

Comment: thanks.that is so nice and clear code from you.could you give me the link of TBXML.h and TBXML.m. because i have downloaded one but its showing me some error.

Comment: With pleasure ;) [Here](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML/blob/master/TBXML-Headers/TBXML.h) you will find the header file, and [here](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML/blob/master/TBXML-Code/TBXML.m) the code file. This is version 1.5, the one I used and worked fine for me.

Comment: sorry to say but here is another problem is  `                if([[TBXML attributeName:element] isEqualToString:@"nameradio"])` showing some waring something like that `incompatible pointer type TBXMLElement* `

Comment: thank you very much for your help but i think my desire answer is my accepted answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can use NSXMLParser :

In your .h file declare :

```
NSMutableData       *webPortFolio;
NSMutableString     *soapResultsPortFolio;
NSURLConnection     *conn;

//---xml parsing---

NSXMLParser         *xmlParserPortFolio;
BOOL                elementFoundPortFolio;
NSMutableURLRequest *req;

NSString            *theXMLPortFolio;
NSString            *strSoapMsg;
UIAlertView         *alertView;
```

In your .m file use the following code:

```
-(void)callURL
{

     //Your logic to call URL.

     conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
     if (conn)
     {
         webPortFolio = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
     }
}
And to handle the response you can use following functions :

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webPortFolio setLength:0];     
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webPortFolio appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error
{

    NSLog(@"error...................%@",[error description]);
    [webPortFolio release];
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{

    //Check the request and returns the response.

    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webPortFolio length]);

    theXMLPortFolio = [[NSString alloc] 
                      initWithBytes: [webPortFolio mutableBytes] 
                      length:[webPortFolio length] 
                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //---shows the XML---

    NSLog(@"shows the XML %@",theXMLPortFolio);
    [theXMLPortFolio release];    

    if(xmlParserPortFolio)
    {
        [xmlParserPortFolio release];
    }
    xmlParserPortFolio = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webPortFolio];
    [xmlParserPortFolio setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParserPortFolio setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParserPortFolio parse];
    [webPortFolio release];
    [connection release];
}

//---when the start of an element is found---
-(void)  parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict
{

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {
        if (!soapResultsPortFolio)
        {
            soapResultsPortFolio = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        elementFoundPortFolio = TRUE;
        NSLog(@"Registration...%@",soapResultsPortFolio);
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {
        elementFoundPortFolio = TRUE;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {
        elementFoundPortFolio = TRUE;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {
        elementFoundPortFolio = TRUE;
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFoundPortFolio)
    {
        [soapResultsPortFolio appendString: string];
    }      
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"Parser error %@ ",[parseError description]);
}


//---when the end of element is found---
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {          
        NSLog(@"display the soap results%@",soapResultsPortFolio);
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {          
        //Perform required action
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {
        //Perform required action
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"your_tag_name"])
    {
        //Perform required action
    }

    [soapResultsPortFolio setString:@""];
    elementFoundPortFolio = FALSE;
}
```