# ios Dictionary to Array "object for key"

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, dictionary

i have a dictionary  and when i write it's element , it is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UrunListesi6Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org//Stok">
      <UrunListesi6Result>
        <Urun6>
          <UrunId>int</UrunId>
        </Urun6>
        <Urun6>
          <UrunId>int</UrunId>
        </Urun6>
      </UrunListesi6Result>
    </UrunListesi6Response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

To take UrunIds in an array, i use

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


a = [[[[[myDictionary  objectForKey:@"soap"]objectForKey:@"UrunListesi6Response" ] objectForKey:@"UrunListesi6Result"] objectForKey:@"Urun6"] objectForKey:@"UrunId"];

NSLog(@"%@",a);
```

But result is null, what is the problem ?

Comment: why not use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: You could use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for parsing this kind of data, it will make your life much easier, you can see this [tutorial on NSXMLParser](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser)

Comment: Where do you get myDictionary from? How do you read/write files?

Answer (score 1):

That is a xml file, not a dictionary.

Read that xml into an NSDictionary then try.

You can use any of XML parsers available.

There are a lot of answers for parsing an XML file, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172669/how-can-i-parse-this-xml-using-nsxmlparser-in-ios) posted today only.

Comment: You're welcome—though you still refer to a plist in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

There are two "soap" keys:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>

</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: `soap` is what is called an XML namespace.